# MongoDB .NET Driver - Using pullFilter to remove string from string array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

I am trying to do a pullFilter and can get it to work on complex types.

```cs
await _Collection.UpdateOneAsync(
Builders<Descriptor>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, id),
Builders<Descriptor>.Update
    .Set(d => d.UpdatedBy, actioner)
    .Set(d => d.UpdatedOn, DateTime.Now)
    .PullFilter(d => d.Options, "Remove this one")
);
```

However, `Options` is an array of string values and I cannot get it to remove the value "Remove this one":

```
{
    "Name" : "Test",
    "Type" : NumberInt(1),
    "Options" : [
        "Testing",
        "Tested",
        "Remove this one"
    ]
}
```

This is my error message:

> "message": "JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Remove'."

I also tried this:

```cs
await _Collection.UpdateOneAsync(
    Builders<Descriptor>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, id),
    Builders<Descriptor>.Update
        .Set(d => d.UpdatedBy, actioner)
        .Set(d => d.UpdatedOn, DateTime.Now)
        .PullFilter(d => d.Options, d => d == "Remove this one")
);
```

which results in this error:

> "message": "{document} is not supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [UpdateDefinitionExtensions.Pull<TDocument, TItem> Method (UpdateDefinition, FieldDefinition, TItem)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionExtensions_Pull__2.htm) instead of `.PullFilter()`.

```cs
await _Collection.UpdateOneAsync(
    Builders<Descriptor>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, id),
    Builders<Descriptor>.Update
        .Set(d => d.UpdatedBy, actioner)
        .Set(d => d.UpdatedOn, DateTime.Now)
        .Pull(d => d.Options, "Remove this one")
);
```

> Demo

[image]